# How to do simple Substring in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How do I do this in Oracle Query? this is saying that we want the records which has '1' inleft most position in that column.

---

```
AND substring(convert(varchar,TR.MENU_ID_VALUE), 1, 1) = '1'
```

Comment: should have said the orig is in sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`convert` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions034.htm#SQLRF00620) function transforms a string from one *character set* into another. The syntax is `convert(<string>, <to character set>, <from character set>)`

Also, `substring` isn't an Oracle function, it's [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114).

If you don't need to convert the string then `and substr(tr.menu_id_value,1,1)` will get you the leftmost character.

If you do want to convert the character set then the full list is [available in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i635016), alternatively you can query [`v$nls_valid_values`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_2076.htm#REFRN30160). For instance if you're converting from WE8MSWIN1252 [(Windows code-page 1252)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) to AL32UTF8 [(UTF-8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) then your condition would become:

```
and substr(convert(tr.menu_id_value,'AL32UTF8','WE8MSWIN1252'),1,1) = '1'
```

---

From your comment I'm guessing that `convert()` is the SQL-Server function to convert between data-types. The Oracle equivalent, in this case, would be [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130). Though Oracle will implicitly do the conversion it is *always* best to use `to_char` and convert explicitly; giving you:

```
and substr(to_char(tr.menu_id_value),1,1) = '1'
```

Incidentally the *exact* Oracle equivalent is [`cast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613). Strictly speaking, `to_char()` should be used if you want to use a [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211), thus `substr(cast tr.menu_id_value as varchar2(10)),1,1)` would also give you what you're after assuming the length of `tr.menu_id_value` was less than or equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR`

```
AND substr(tr.menu_id_value,1,1) = '1'
```